# Regex to add space between unicode words/numbers in python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, nlp, indic

I tried using the basic regex for unicodes but I am not able to make them work on the string with characters other than the traditional A-Z and numbers

I am looking at examples from multiple languages not part of the A-Z Alphabetical family

```
text = "20किटल"
res = re.sub("^[^\W\d_]+$", lambda ele: " " + ele[0] + " ", text)

Output:
20किटल
```

2nd try:

```
regexp1 = re.compile('^[^\W\d_]+$', re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
regexp1.sub("^[^\W\d_]+$", lambda ele: " " + ele[0] + " ", text)

 Output:
 20किटल


Expected output:
**20 किटल**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Pypi regex library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import regex

text = "20किटल"
pat = regex.compile(r"(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})", re.UNICODE)
res = pat.sub(" ", text)
print res
```

Where `\p{L}` stand for any letter in any language

**Output:**

```
20 किटल
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, would you try the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

text = '20किटल'
print(re.sub(r'([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)([^\s0-9a-zA-Z_]+)', r'\1 \2', text))
```

Output:

```
20 किटल
```